# When is safe wrapping legacy raw pointers from factories with smart pointers?

Tags: c++11, factory, smart-pointers

When is safe to wrap in smart pointers (unique_ptr or shared_ptr) the raw pointers returned by factories of C++ frameworks started to develop before c++11?

For example when everything happen within the same function:

```cpp
int main(int argc,char** argv)
 {
  //.....
  auto* runManager = G4RunManagerFactory::CreateRunManager(G4RunManagerType::Default);
  //... many lines later
  delete runManager;
 }
```

It believe that it is harmless to put the returned raw pointer in a `unique_ptr` and take out the delete at the end of the function.

But besides this specific case, I am not sure if there are other cases in which this can be done safely - and your code gain in readability / maintainability is worth the effort.

In particular I am using a C++ framework toolkit that developed its own way of tracking and disposing the objects created by the framework, so I should have to think twice (or more) before using the returned pointers in a way not originally intended.

Any suggestion is very welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only when ownership of object pointed by returned value is transferred to user (i.e. you, who write the code calling that factory). An object returned by factory might be actually owned by framework and would be destroyed properly and (almost) never lost. Using smart pointer on those would result in problems, mainly double deletion.

An example of such is Qt framework, where all visual elements destroy their children when they are destroyed and all QObject elements ar "enumerated". A factory there is hidden from user and mostly related to signal-slot system and metaobject data. There are special cases where smart pointers can be used, but Qt provides own flavor of those.

A factory that doesn't own created objects may require some custom steps to delete object directly, in that case you should use proper deleters for smart pointer.

There is a little misunderstanding about statement that in modern C++ "raw pointers are bad". It actually must be worded  "raw *owning* pointers are bad". If you loose value of raw pointer and there is nothing in program that stores its value for purpose of proper deallocation and releasing of resources, it's an owning pointer.

Comment: However whenever I read (the framework provides many "user code examples" for many of its classes) that it is MY duty to delete the object obtained from the factory, as in the example above, this means that it returns a owning pointer, which can be replaced... right?
<br/>
Sometimes (again from "user code examples") even user classes have to embed pointers to framework objects that must be initialized (sometimes from factories, sometimes with "new") in the constructor and the corresponding "delete" is required in the destructors. This seems to me again a case where unique_ptr can be used